# Switch Spring annotations depends on active profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following configuration for Spock class which is responsible for running integration tests.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AccountService.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Sql(executionPhase= Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD,scripts="classpath:/integration-tests/clear-tables.sql")
@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase
class AccountControllerIntegrationSpec extends Specification
{
.....
}
```

I have two profiles. The purpose is to active use set of annotations :

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Sql(executionPhase= Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD,scripts="classpath:/integration-tests/clear-tables.sql")
```

when I run `docker-test` profile.
When I run profile `test` I would like to use only `@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase (postgress embedded database for tests)`.

Profile `test-docker` should use real database from other container.

Profile `test` should use embedded database Postgress when I run tests locally on machine.

How can I configure during startup spring to choose databaseSource ?
When I add both annontations each time Embedded Postgres is only active even if test-docker profile is active I tried to set scope of dependency for embedded Postgres set differently for profiles. But it did not help.

Comment: Maybe you could extract those annotations to separate configuration (annotated with `@Configuration`) and use [`@Profile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) annotation to turn it on or off based on active profile.

Comment: @michalk How about scope dependency then ?

Comment: @michalk this annotation must be applied directly for test class.

Comment: Use Spring / maven profiles and `@Profile` the test classes you want to differentiate. This way, depending on the active *profile*, those Tests will be called or not.